# Angular live search

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to build a search form with angular.
**If needed, I can give you a Jsfiddle.**
I've got a contact list, rendered through an object.

contact object example:

```
{
  'name': ' Jon',
  'job' : 'developer',
  'country' : 'USA'
}
```

If I write in my input "Jon Developer USA", the result will be every contacts who are called Jon, are developers AND live in USA...

My html/angular loop + input:

```
<input ng-keyup="resultArrayFilterMultiple(searchResult)" ng-model="searchResult" type="text" name="">

<div ng-repeat="contact in contacts_result = (contacts | limitTo : limit)>....</div>
```

My javascript :

```
  $scope.resultArrayFilterMultiple = function(searchTxt){

    var tableCur = searchTxt.toString().split(' ');
    var obj = {};

    if(tableCur.length > 0){
        var result = $scope.customFilter(tableCur, obj);
    }

};


 $scope.customFilter = function(tableCur, obj){

    for(var i = 0; i < tableCur.length; i++) {

        if (tableCur[i].length >= 3) {
            angular.forEach($scope.persons, function (contact) {
                if (contact.name.indexOf(tableCur[i]) >= 0 || contact.job.indexOf(tableCur[i]) >= 0 || contact.country.indexOf(tableCur[i]) >= 0) {
                    obj.push(contact);
                    $scope.persons = obj;
                }
            });

    }


};
```

Any suggestions to solve it ? It works for the first word but I don't know how to filter with a second or a third one.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AngularJS filter property just as below. NO JavaScript code is needed..

```
<ng-repeat="contact in contacts_result| filter: searchText">
```

Comment: Nope, that's not enough for what I want. That's why I ask

Comment: Could you please create a fiddle so that I can check .

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom fitler for that. Something like:

```
app.filter('customFilter', function() { 
    return function(input, searchCriteria) {
        var out = [];
        var searchCriteriaPieces = searchCriteria.split(" ");
        angular.forEach(input, function(item){
            if(//logic to decide if item meets searchcriteria){
               out.push(item);
            }
        })

        return out;
    }
}
});
```

With an html like

```
<div ng-repeat="contact in contacts_result = (contacts | customFilter:searchResult)>....</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter):

```
moduleName.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(input, searchText) {
        var out = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
            for(var k in item) { /* walkthrough all properties */
                if( item[k] == searchText )  {
                    out.push(item);
                }
            }
        });
        return out;
    }
})
```

Then, use the proper markup in order to instruct Angular how to use filter:

```
<div>
    <input ng-model="searchText" type="text" name="">
    <div ng-repeat="person in persons | customFilter:searchText">{{person.name}} {{person.country}} {{person.job}}</div>
</div>
```

You might want to improve it a bit in order to achieve better search results, e.g. trim input, etc.